# Can a RAW socket be bound to an ip:port instead of an interface?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I need to write a proxy server in C language on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04). The purpose of this proxy server is as follows. There're illogical governmental barriers in accessing the free internet. Some are:

1. Name resolution: I ping telegram.org and many other sites which the government doesn't want me to access. I ask 8.8.8.8 to resolve the name, but they response of behalf of the server that the IP may be resolved to 10.10.34.35!

Let's concentrate on this one, because when this is solved many other problems will be solved too. For this, I need to setup such a configuration:

1. A server outside of my country is required. I prepared it. It's a VPS. Let's call it RS (Remote Server).
2. A local proxy server is required. Let's call it PS. PS runs on the local machine (client) and knows RS's IP. I need it to gather all requests going to be sent through the only NIC available on client, process them, scramble them, and send them to RS in a way to be hidden from the government.
3. The server-side program should be running on RS on a specific port to get the packet, unscramble it, and send it to the internet on behalf of the client. After receiving the response from the internet, it should send it back to the client via the PS.
4. PS will deliver the response to the client application which originates the request. Of course this happens after it will unscramble and will find the original response from the internet.

This is the design and some parts is remained gloomy for me. Since I'm not an expert in network programming context, I'm going to ask my questions in the parts I'm getting into trouble or are not clear for me.

Now, I'm in part 2. See whether I'm right. There're two types of sockets, a RAW socket and a stream socket. A RAW socket is opened this way:

```
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

And a stream socket is opened this way:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

For RAW sockets, we use sockaddr_ll and for stream sockets we use sockaddr_in. May I use stream sockets between client applications and PS? I think not, because I need the whole RAW packet. I should know the protocol and maybe some other info of the packet, because the whole packet should be retrieved transparently in RS. For example, I should know whether it has been a ping packet (ICMP) or a web request (TCP). For this, I need to have packet header in PS. So I can't use a stream socket, because it doesn't contain the packet header. But until now, I've used RAW sockets for interfaces and have not written a proxy server to receive RAW packets. Is it possible? In another words, I've the following questions to go to next step:

1. Can a RAW socket be bound to localhost:port instead of an interface so that it may receive all low-level packets containing packet headers (RAW packets)?
2. I may define a proxy server for browser. But can I put the whole system behind the proxy server so that packets of other apps like PING may route automatically via it?
3. Do I really need RAW sockets in PS? Can't I change the design to suffice the data I got from the packets payload?

Maybe I'm wrong in some of the concepts and will appreciate your guidance.

Thank you

Comment: If you can control the remote server, then why not configure a DNS server on that machine that will forward your requests? This will allow validation of the approach without any custom software. Then, you can later add constraints to prevent it from becoming an open DNS relay for all and sundry. If it is inside a VPN, then perhaps not even necessary.

Comment: Assume that 8.8.8.8 is the destination IP for a packet of type DNS. In this case, the governmental machines between client and 8.8.8.8 monitor this packet and send reply back to the client on behalf of 8.8.8.8. They create a response packet with source IP 8.8.8.8, while 8.8.8.8 has no idea about such a packet. Client thinks that the answer is really from 8.8.8.8, while it's not. In the response packet the name is resolved to 10.10.34.35. Now, when this happens to 8.8.8.8, why it doesn't happen to my server? Such a packet never gets the opportunity to get outside of my country.

Comment: The entire point of a VPN is that traffic is private. Your DNS request will be forwarded to your server in a safe location. It will relay your DNS request and return the response. The Government cannot see the content and does not know the request may in the end have gone through to 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Okay, so I need to setup a VPN server on my server, not a DNS server;

Comment: The VPN allows you to access the remote network privately. Depending on the configuration of the VPN you may not need to implement a local DNS to allow forwarding of the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a RAW socket be bound to localhost:port instead of an interface so that it may receive all low-level packets containing packet headers (RAW packets)?

No, it doesn't make sense. Raw packets don't have port numbers so how would it know which socket to go to?

---

It looks like you are trying to write a VPN. You can do this on Linux by creating a *fake network interface* called a "tun interface". You create a tun interface, and whenever Linux tries to send a packet through the interface, instead of going to a network cable, it goes to your program! Then you can do whatever you like with the packet. Of course, it works both ways - you can send packets from your program back to Linux through the tun interface, and Linux will act like they just arrived on a network cable.

Then, you can set up your routing table so that all traffic goes to the tun interface, except for traffic to the VPN server ("RS"), which goes to your real ethernet/wifi interface. Otherwise you'd have an endless loop where your VPN program PS tried to send packets to RS but they just went back to PS.

Comment: Good idea. Seems I need a good tutorial, guide, document or sample program in C.

Comment: I marked your answer as the answer, although my knowledge in not still sufficient to judge about it. :D

Comment: Now let's discuss more about your solution. You say RAW packets don't have port numbers. Please describe it. Any packet has source IP, source port, destination IP and destination port. So what does you mean by this sentence?

Comment: And about routing, assume that my server (RS) real IP be 1.2.3.4, do I need to assign an IP to the tun interface? Is it sufficient to add the following routes? sudo ip route add default dev tun0; sudo ip route add 1.2.3.4 dev enp2s0

Comment: If I got it correctly, how can I programmatically (in C) add the temporary interface, change route table and at exist revert everything to its normal state? If the dummy interface remains permanent and will be existing even after reboot, I may neglect adding and removing it via inside PS.

Comment: @hamidi Port numbers are part of TCP and UDP. Because you use a raw socket, the OS does not interpret the TCP and UDP parts of the packet.

Comment: @hamidi Yes it's complicated, if it was simple I could've just said which functions to use. You can also buy somebody else's VPN software. Even other peoples' VPN software has problems where the routes don't change back if the software crashes. The interface is not permanent, it only stays as long as your program has it open.

Comment: Oh no! Why going to buy while I've my dedicated server and I'm an expert C programmer. My lack is just least of my knowledge about network. And about port numbers, the RAW packet contains source and destination ports, and I don't want OS to process it and extract them for me. Since the structure of an IP packet is clear, I may examine whether it's an IP packet. If the packet is not I'll forward it as is and if not I may scramble the content and send it to RS. This is what I've to do, I think. Everything is gloomy for me at the moment. Tun interface may be a clue to know where to begin from.

Comment: I created tun0 dummy interface and by using ip route could cause all traffics to be routed through this interface. As the first step I created a bridge between tun0 and enp0s3 so that the internet may be visible to the whole system. Now all traffic is routed through tun0 and it forwards it to the internet. So everything is okay, but the name resolution. When I ping 4.2.2.4, I see the response without any problem, but google.com can't be pinged. The name is not resolved. How can I overcome this barrier? I tried changing /etc/resolv.conf manually with no success.

Comment: @hamidi I would use wireshark to debug. DNS is port 53 and you can get wireshark to only show port 53 UDP packets